# AzureDevops check-in error: Could not find file

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I have added a new project in the existing solution but Getting error 'Could not find file c:\path...' while I am trying to check-in the changes on Azure devops. File is running fine in local and also included in the pending changes.

I can not rollback the changes as its new project.

Couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: Try using command line git commands. Have you tried adding all changes from top root directory with "git add ." or try "git status" to check the status.

Comment: We are not using git. I was trying to check-in using source control.

Comment: ah, you mean TFVC? I think it should help to add the file manually in TFVC Explorer from Visual studio.